# using directive and declaration in C++

Tags: c++, reference

does using directive has local scope??

i find in C++ primer book that  " a using directive in a function treats the namespace names as being declared outside the function"

if it is like declared outside a function why  doesn’t it make those names available to other functions in the file.

```
namespace Jill 
{ 
    double bucket(double n) { ... } 
    double fetch; 
    struct Hill { ... }; 
}
int main()
{
    using namespace Jill;
    return 0;
}
int foom()
{
    Hill top;              //error
    Jill::Hill crest;     //valid
}
```

if the statement "a using directive in a function treats the namespace names as being declared outside the function" is true than

```
`Hill top`
```

would have been valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> " a using directive in a function treats the namespace names as being declared outside the function"

The namespace names are treated as being declared outside the function, but it won't change the behavior of the implement of other functions, i.e. these names would be visible only in the function instroducing the using directive, they won't be visible in any other functions.

On the other hand, if there's a local function declaration in the function scope, it will be selected firstly other than the one introduced by the using directive.

e.g.

```
namespace Jill 
{ 
    double bucket(double n) { std::cout << "Jill::bucket\n"; return 0.0; } 
    double fetch; 
    struct Hill {}; 
}

int main()
{
    double bucket(double);
    using namespace Jill;
    bucket(0.0); // ::bucket but not Jill::bucket will be selected
    return 0;
}

double bucket(double n) { std::cout << "::bucket\n"; return 0.0; }
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vHJJmfU0WSrA1iLl)

Comment: " a using directive in a function treats the namespace names as being declared outside the function"     what is the meaning of as being declared outside the function if other function cant use it?

Comment: @AAYUSHNEUPANE It's its purpose.  By adding `using` to the function scope, you affect only this function. `using` changes behavior of name lookup in scope where it 's present.  Changing behavior of name lookup in global scope affects everything and possibly may cause problems.

Comment: @AAYUSHNEUPANE • Other function can put in `using namespace Jill;` too.